# I just changed the visual style of my Visual C# Express 2010, and now intellisense doesn't pop up unless I press ctrl+SpaceKey

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-express

What can I do to fix this?

I only imported a settings file for the IDE to change the colors, etc. Any help on how to make intellisense pop up like normal. Now I have to use the Ctrl+SpaceKey combo to make it show.

Thanks SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Auto list members.